# Comparing and replacing items in two lists with different sizes in Kotlin?

Tags: android, list, collections, kotlin

I have the following function:

```
override fun insertUpdatedItems(items: List<AutomobileEntity>) {
        if (!items.isEmpty()) {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, automobileEntity ->
                if (automobileEntity.id == items[index].id) {
                    automobileCollection[index] = items[index]
                    notifyItemInserted(index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using to provide data for a recyclerview, I'm trying to insert updated/edited items that are already in `automobileCollection` which size always returns `10` items but the `items` list might differ it can be `1` to `10`.

It's supposed to compare items by `id` but what I'm getting currently with this function is the edited items are just inserted to recyclerview's adapter and not treated as an already existing item.

On the contrary, if I iterate using `automobileCollection` I get IndexOutOfBoundsException since most of the time the `items` list is smaller than `automobileCollection`.

Comment: you can skip the outer condition. if `items` would be empty, `forEachIndexed` just does nothing... You iterate over `items` with `index` and then you compare it to itself (`automobileEntry` is an element of `items`). With this found item (which is basically *each*) you use that index (of the items list!!!) to update the unrelated `automobileCollection` ... what do you want to achieve actually? And please be sure that you understand what I wrote before... this is essential to deal with `forEach`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

To update a list with items from another one, you can use several ways.

First starting with a direct replacement (which preserves the order, but that's just a detail):

```
val sourceList = TODO()
val targetList = TODO()

targetList.replaceAll { targetItem -> 
  sourceList.firstOrNull { targetItem.id == it.id } 
            ?: targetItem
}
```

Alternatively removing all the items and adding them again:

```
targetList.removeIf { targetItem ->
  sourceList.any { it.id == targetItem.id }
}
targetList.addAll(sourceList)
```

Using listIterator (note! that's actually also happening under the hood when you call `replaceAll`... not in the same way, but similar ;-)):

```
val iterator = targetList.listIterator()
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  iterator.next().apply {
    sourceList.firstOrNull { id == it.id }?.also(iterator::set)
  }
}
```

Probably not so readable... For your `forEachIndexed` I do not really see any use-case. For other problems there definitely are, but I would suggest you try to omit indices (and also `forEach`) as often as you can. If nothing better comes to your mind, then `forEach` is also ok, but many times, `forEach` (and even more so `forEachIndexed`) isn't the best approach to solve an issue.